# Tracking user clicks back to Google Adwords API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am going around in circles a bit with this one trying to find a solution online and I cant find one so I thought I would ask then it may be useful to others as well.

The scenario.

With PHP I am looking to talk back to the Google Adwords API. OK not a biggy. However I want to tie it in with our own back office system to marry up data from sales/conversions to impressions/clicks/costs of each campaign/adgroup in Google Adwords.

This would involve tagging the destination URLs I initially thought with the dynamic tag from Google of {creative} for example http://www.mydomain.com/productone/?adid={creative} however this appears to be a number which is not unique across the account but unique only under Adgroup. So AdgroupOne and AdgroupTwo could both have an adid of 1,2,3,4,5 etc.. Therefore you cannot use this id to pull the data.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a way of getting around it to get a unique indentifier which can be stored in the backoffice with each visit to trace back to Google Adwords via their API?

Really appreciate the help with this one as its got me stumped. Thanks guys.

Comment: Definitely seems that {creative} is related to the id of the adcopy in relation to an adgroup.

Comment: Looking further into it again {keyword} seems to relate to the keyword/phrase that is in an adgroup but not what the actual user puts in. This could then possibly be referenced back to the GA API to pull which adgroup it is under?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be to provide your own ids in the url. Also maintain a map at your end, of the form (adgroupid, adId, your_tag_id). This way you can lookup the map to figure out what Ad was clicked when a url is hit.

Some id rules to keep in mind:

campaignId: Unique across system.
adGroupId: Unique across system.
adId: Unique within an adGroupId, so (adGroupId, adId) is unique across the system.
keywordId: Unique within an adGroupId, so (adGroupId, keywordId) is unique across the system.

Cheers,
Anash